Some questions about Aristotelian genus-species frame
Some question about Aristotelian genus-species frame
For Aristotle, if essence must be defined in terms of genus + speceific differentia.
1 / Does the highest genus (category) have no essence? (Does the substance itself have no essence?)
2 / Only Individual can have essence？
3 / If only substances are placed in genus-species (Really?): are there no species in other genera than substance?

While the highest genus without higher genus might have a general nature, Aristotle would say it lacks an everywhere definable essence in the strict sense because essence requires a higher genus plus differentia and belongs to the species. Though substance (ousia) is the primordial and highest categorical genus in Aristotle's framework, individual substances (e.g. Socrates, this white horse) are the paradigms of entities with essences in Aristotlian categorization only because individuals have essences in the sense that they only instantiate the essence of their species...

@DoubleKnot: That looks like an Answer to me...

See A's Categories:

Aristotle’s second classificatory system is a list of the highest kinds, which are also known as categories. That there are highest kinds (or perhaps that there is one single highest kind) can be motivated by noticing the fact that the ordinary objects of our experience fall into classes of increasing generality. [...] Does it end, in other words, at a highest kind? It might seem that the answer to this question is obvious: of course there is a highest kind — being. After all, someone might argue, everything exists. So the class that contains all and only beings must be the class with the greatest possible extension. In the Metaphysics, however, Aristotle argues that being is not a genus (998b23, 1059b31). According to Aristotle, every genus must be differentiated by some differentia that falls outside that genus. Hence, if being were a genus, it would have to be differentiated by a differentia that fell outside of it. In other words, being would have to be differentiated by some non-being, which, according to Aristotle, is a metaphysical absurdity. Although he does not explicitly make this claim, Aristotle’s argument, if cogent, would generalize to any proposal for a single highest kind. Hence, he does not think that there is one single highest kind. Instead, he thinks that there are ten: (1) substance; (2) quantity; (3) quality; (4) relatives; (5) somewhere; (6) sometime; (7) being in a position; (8) having; (9) acting; and (10) being acted upon (Cat, 1b25–2a4).

Maybe there is a tension with the ten-categories theoty (Categories book seems older) than subsequent Metaphysics' theory of substance:

The primacy of substance leads Aristotle to say that the age-old question ‘What is being?’ “is just the question ‘What is substance?’” (1028b4). One might have thought that this question had already been answered in the Categories. There we were given, as examples of primary substances, an individual man or horse, and we learned that a primary substance is “what is neither in a subject nor said of a subject” (2a10). This would seem to provide us with both examples of, and criteria for being, primary substances. But in Met Ζ, Aristotle does not seem to take either the examples or the criteria for granted.


In Ζ he recounts the various answers that have been given to the question of which things are substances—bodies (including plants, animals, the parts of plants and animals, the elements, the heavenly bodies), things more basic than bodies (surfaces, lines, and points), imperceptible things (such as Platonic Forms and mathematical objects)—and seems to regard them all as viable candidates at this point. He does not seem to doubt that the clearest examples of substances are perceptible ones, but leaves open the question whether there are others as well.


Before answering this question about examples, however, he says that we must first answer the question about criteria: what is it to be a substance? The negative criterion (“neither in a subject nor said of a subject”) of the Categories tells us only which things are substances. But even if we know that something is a substance, we must still say what makes it a substance—what the cause is of its being a substance. This is the question to which Aristotle next turns. To answer it is to identify, as Aristotle puts it, the substance of that thing.


Your questions about Aristotle's genus-species framework address key issues in his metaphysics. Let’s examine each point:

Does the highest genus (category) lack an essence? (Does matter itself lack an essence?)
According to Aristotle, the definition of anything requires a genus and a specific difference. The highest genus (e.g., being), which has no genus above it, cannot be defined in this way because it lacks a higher genus.

Nevertheless, Aristotle believes the highest genus (being) has an essence in a broad, all-encompassing sense that includes everything else. However, this essence is not definable in terms of genus and specific difference. As for matter, it cannot have an essence in itself because matter, for Aristotle, is pure potentiality. Without form, it has no intrinsic characteristics or essence.

Can only individuals possess substance (essence)?
In Aristotle's metaphysics, substance (ousia) is divided into two levels:

Primary substance: Individual entities (e.g., Socrates, this particular horse).
Secondary substance: Species and genera (e.g., human, horse).
Individuals are considered primary substances because they have actual existence. Species and genera are also regarded as substances in a secondary sense, but their existence depends on individuals. Therefore, it can be argued that only individuals possess essence in the strictest sense, as they have concrete and unique existence.

If only substances are placed within a genus-species framework (is this true?): Are there no species within genera other than substance?
Not exactly. Aristotle does not limit the genus-species framework to substances. He uses it to organize other categories as well, but substance applies specifically to physical and tangible entities.

In other categories, like quality or quantity, there can be division into species, but these are not substances. For example:
In the genus quality, there are species like color or shape.
However, these species do not have independent existence; they are attributes of substances.
Thus, the genus-species framework applies to all categories, but substance is unique to physical entities.
Summary
The highest genus (e.g., being or matter) cannot be defined and lacks an essence in the usual sense.
Only individuals have essence in the strict sense, though species and genera are substances in a secondary sense.
The genus-species framework applies to all categories, but substance specifically pertains to physical entities.

But sorry, Being is not a genus.

1 / Idk, still. but there probably is.
2 / Things outside the physical individual can have essences, but only the individual, as a primary substanbce, has an essence in focal sense.

Species and genera that are secondary substance also have essences, but only have essences as secondary substance.
Species and genera that are not substances also have essences, but are essences in a secondary sense.
But just as being is said of in many senses, so are essences said of in many ways.

3 / Many universals other than secondary substances are embedded in the genus-species fram: quantities, qualities, relations, when? Where? What posture? Having, bearing, doing.
